# How do I update to the latest MythTV release?

Tags: mythtv, mythbuntu

I want to update to the latest MythTV release, but it isn't available in the Ubuntu repository. Where can I get it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mythbuntu team provides updated MythTV versions though the MythTV-Updates repository for Ubuntu (and by extension all Ubuntu derivatives). This can be done by adding the Mythbuntu-repos package that is [available here](http://www.mythbuntu.org/repos).